# This site can't be reached after moving the wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I was using WordPress and later I backup my all data and database to move it into another computer. I moved all my files in **www** directory in **wamp** server. Everything was fine but I encountered an error,

> Error in login into the database.

SO after googling I changed my username, database name, and password in **wp-config.php** accordingly. Everything was fine but now it is showing

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

[image]

I though again I am not able to login, so I tried to change the name to my another Wordpress database, and it is opening well. So I thought it is not login in my database, so I create a file and logged in manually to check the username, password and database name. And it show that I am logged in successfully. SO what I'm missing here and why can't I access wordpress site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours. And after searching a lot, I found that **ThreadStackSize** limit in my new computer (where I was shifting my whole WordPress stuff) was not defined (or not enough). 
So I think your Wordpress data must be large enough that exceeds **ThreadStackSize**.

So U think this will resolve your issue.

1. Click on the green wamp icon in the tray icons (right side of your taskbar.)
2. Now goto **apache>httpd.conf**.
3. Now search for **ThreadStackSize** in that file.

   1. If found then increase the number return after **ThreadStackSize** to a higher value like **8388608**.
   2. Or if not found then write the following text in the bottom of the file and save it.

`

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

4. Now click again on the green **wamp** icon in the icon tray and then restart the wamp server.
5. There's no any step five, just reload the page. And all is done.

Answer (score 0):

If it's WAMP server the problem can be resolved by TreadStackSize but if you seeing it on production it has got more to do with DNS Lookup, DNS Propagation and SSL certificates.

Sorry for not being direct because you haven't provided the configuration of the setup.