# localhost refused to connect after migrating with Duplicator; wp-admin dashboard works fine

Tags: php, wordpress, database-migration, httpd.conf

I created a duplicator database only backup and then did the two-part install. The install seemed to go fine and I can login to the Dashboard, but when I launch the homepage it says:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The closest issue similar to mine is this: [This site can't be reached after moving the wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032767/this-site-cant-be-reached-after-moving-the-wordpress-site)

I checked my ThreadStackSize as instructed and it was already set at 888 8888. I increased to 9999 9999 and restarted my WAMP64 server, to no avail.

I tried removing all the plugins. No love. It still didn't change anything. I accounted for possible caching issues in Chrome by launching in incognito mode. Still same error on home page.

So, why can I log in to the Dashboard (wp-admin/wp-login) just fine, but the homepage won't launch?

Answer (score 0):

This solutin solved my problem(if not use mysql on docker this not solved your problem):
If use Mysql on docker you must  use `network name` in composer file instead of localhost .
For example you nust use `db` for host instead of localhost .

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEdqT.png)

Comment: Not using MySQL on docker, just a plain windows machine

Answer (score -1):

Did you updated Site Link and Paths within database? Also, open Permalinks under Settings in the dashboard and press save without changing anything. I believe it will fix your issue as these are common errors after migration.

Comment: Also try to rename .htaccess file inside your WordPress installation directory.

Comment: Yes, I did. I toggled from "post name" to "post id". Didn't fix it.

Comment: Ahmad, thanks for the .htaccess suggestion. I know what .htaccess is, but I'm not familiar with manipulating and configuring it. And my wordpress install seems to be creating multiple .htaccess files in the same directory. Everything's been working fine (until today) so I guess that is normal? Can you provide step by step instruction and add it to the body of your answer?

Comment: There should be 1 .htaccess file, multiple .htaccess files are not possible, if there're, they should be earlier backups and with different names. Look for the exact match '.htaccess' , rename it to '.htaccess1' then go to permalinks, select Post Name and save. Lets see if it works..

Comment: I did not get to try your .htaccess solution because all of a sudden it worked. The only thing I had changed was I gave up and ran Ccleaner while I left for about 30 minutes. When I tried to launch the local site just now, it worked fine. `Any idea why running Ccleaner would fix it it, but running in incognito mode (which ensures that there is no caching) didn't?`